# PHP 7.3.8 Snowflake connection in Mac Os Catalina not working

Tags: php, macos, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm building the PHP dashboard application with data from snowflake

I'm using the  PHP 7.3.8 version.
I'm trying to build the odbc.so file but no success with mac os.
i have try researching but most of the article are base on Linux or Windows machine.

i have try with the pdo drivers but i'm getting the below error message
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in....18 Stack trace: #0 /...Stack trace: #0 /

odbc driver error message:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in ... Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

I think both the error mostly because of the missing drivers but i have also try with
with unixodbc

brew install unixodbc but don't know how to connect or configure with php?

please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: You may also get some traction on https://apple.stackexchange.com/